# How can I fix computer that won’t even boot up

Tags: windows-10, drivers, disk-cleanup

I just had to update my drivers and clean my disk due to high disk usage, I went to reset and now my screen just stays plane black, it’ll change to a white screen for a split second every once in awhile, but won’t actually let me on. Please help

Comment: Can you boot some other OS, like a Linux distro on a LiveCD ?  If so, and you have enough external storage you can backup your stuff and reinstall...  Also try booting in safe mode - if you have a really big disk, it could be running a forced disk check... which could take a LONG time

Comment: @ivanivan I don’t even have another OS, I think I might just have to completely reinstall

Comment: @ivanivan also forgot to mention I can’t even boot into safe mode

Comment: Have you tried booting into Last Known Good Configuration?  I'm presuming you are only having issues when Windows 10 is booting and that it passes the POST.

Comment: @Enigman won’t even go into start up, I think the disk might have died on me, and I need a new hard drive, but I’m not sure.

Comment: @Enigman thank you for your answers I don’t know what I did but I got it working by spamming enter and just kept retrying a graphics drive restart. I’m not sure how to process though in all honesty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the first things I do when I have issues:

- Unplug the power cable from the computer and press the power button to drain the capacitors off all power. Then plug the power cable back in and try to boot.
- If you're using a laptop, then remove the battery and the power cable and hold the power button till lights go out, which should be almost instantaneously.
- Try and connect the video cable to a different video port on the computer, and if you have a graphics card, try to use a port that is coming from the motherboard instead of the graphics card.
- Try a spare monitor, or a TV if you can
- If at all possible, boot from a USB or CD that has Linux on it, such as Ubuntu or Mint. This will test things such as the monitor, the computer hardware, and other components that will narrow down the problem.

Moving on:

- What Operating System are you using?
- Are you using a laptop or a tower computer?
- Do you have a graphics card installed and what model is it if so?
- What drivers do you try to update and what process did you go about updating them? Like Windows Update or some third party tool?

Before you do any wiping and reinstalling, as long as there is no foul play like malware or hard drive failure, your data should be able to be recovered. It's as simple as taking the hard drive out, connecting it to another computer by a SATA to USB adapter, and copying the files to a new location then wiping the disk and reinstalling and copying the files back over to the freshly installed OS.

Sorry for the all the questions, but it will help to narrow down the problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks man, I ended up getting it figured out, not sure what the problem was, but it did end up resolved after much spamming. Right now I’m just updating windows just in case that was an issue which it most likely was. Very helpful though, I run through the same process you do.

Comment: Sounds good! Good luck Tallon!

Comment: Thanks, by the way this community is so much nicer than the chemistry community in all honesty